# parse lists from nested json objects

Tags: sql, json, list, nested, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my s3 bucket, I have a json that looks like this. The "data" object is further nested with objects that have lists.

```json
[
    {
        "metadata": {
            "site": "first",
            "aggregation": "DAY",
            "date": "2023-04-12",
            "stage": "CODE",
            "exported_at": "2023-04-14T07:44:55",
            "version": "1"
        },
        "data": {
            "level1": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                }
            ],
            "level2": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2152417,
                    "code": "and001111121",
                    "preliminary": false
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 73020,
                    "code": "and001111221",
                    "preliminary": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I want to parse the json such that each item in the lists (level1, level2) are parsed into separate rows. So the outcome looks like this:

```
site    aggregation  date     exported_at    SYSTEM   datetime     pis   code
                                             LEVEL1
                                             LEVEL1
                                             LEVEL2
                                             LEVEL2
```

I tried this and it works but this only considers "level1". How can I parse the json such that it automatically reads all list objects within "data" and puts their title into a separate column "SYSTEM" as well.

```sql
SELECT
  t.$1:metadata.site::STRING AS site,
  t.$1:metadata.aggregation::string as aggregation,
  t.$1:metadata.date::string as ivw_date,
  t.$1:metadata.exported_at::string as exported_at,
  t.$1:metadata.version::string as version,
  iomb.value:datetime::string as datetime,
  iomb.value:pis::number as pis,
  iomb.value:code::string as code,
  metadata$filename as FILE_NAME,
  UUID_STRING() as LOAD_ID,
  TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as LOAD_DATE
FROM @STG.S3/ivw_new/prod/(
  FILE_FORMAT => STG.JSON_NO_OUTER,
  pattern => '.*filename.json'
) t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.$1:data.level1) level1;
```

Answer (score 1):

So fiddling with this question to understand the problem.
Using a single CTE for the fakedata to avoid making a file, I then have to loop across the array, which I assume your file format is doing thus this code is a useful reproduction starting point:

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json(column1) from values
    ('[{
        "metadata": {
            "site": "first",
            "aggregation": "DAY",
            "date": "2023-04-12",
            "stage": "CODE",
            "exported_at": "2023-04-14T07:44:55",
            "version": "1"
        },
        "data": {
            "level1": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                }
            ],
            "level2": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2152417,
                    "code": "and001111121",
                    "preliminary": false
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 73020,
                    "code": "and001111221",
                    "preliminary": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }]')
)
SELECT
  t.value:metadata.site::STRING AS site,
  t.value:metadata.aggregation::string as aggregation,
  t.value:metadata.date::string as ivw_date,
  t.value:metadata.exported_at::string as exported_at,
  t.value:metadata.version::string as version,
  level1.value:datetime::string as datetime,
  level1.value:pis::number as pis,
  level1.value:code::string as code,
  'fakedata' as FILE_NAME
  -- UUID_STRING() as LOAD_ID,
  --TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as LOAD_DATE
FROM data as d,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => d.json) as t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.value:data.level1) level1;
```

which gives:

| SITE | AGGREGATION | IVW_DATE | EXPORTED_AT | VERSION | DATETIME | PIS CODE | FILE_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | DAY | 2023-04-12 | 2023-04-14T07:44:55 | 1 | 2023-04-12T00:00:00 2,108,869 | and001111121 | fakedata |
| first | DAY | 2023-04-12 | 2023-04-14T07:44:55 | 1 | 2023-04-12T00:00:00 2,108,869 | and001111121 | fakedata |

and the question being "how to get the level2 results also:

but first lets "unroll the outer array so the code looks close to your experience of the file handling, lucky you have not provided multiple objects in the top level array, so we can just drop that:

```
with data(json) as (
    select parse_json(column1) from values
    ('{
        "metadata": {
            "site": "first",
            "aggregation": "DAY",
            "date": "2023-04-12",
            "stage": "CODE",
            "exported_at": "2023-04-14T07:44:55",
            "version": "1"
        },
        "data": {
            "level1": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2108869,
                    "code": "and001111121"
                }
            ],
            "level2": [
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 2152417,
                    "code": "and001111121",
                    "preliminary": false
                },
                {
                    "datetime": "2023-04-12T00:00:00",
                    "pis": 73020,
                    "code": "and001111221",
                    "preliminary": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }')
)
SELECT
  t.json:metadata.site::STRING AS site,
  t.json:metadata.aggregation::string as aggregation,
  t.json:metadata.date::string as ivw_date,
  t.json:metadata.exported_at::string as exported_at,
  t.json:metadata.version::string as version,
  level1.value:datetime::string as datetime,
  level1.value:pis::number as pis,
  level1.value:code::string as code,
  'fakedata' as FILE_NAME
  -- UUID_STRING() as LOAD_ID,
  --TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as LOAD_DATE
FROM data as t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.json:data.level1) level1;
```

Now we have that done, we can actually "flatten" the `data` object, and get each member, thus:

```
SELECT
  t.json:metadata.site::STRING AS site,
  t.json:metadata.aggregation::string as aggregation,
  t.json:metadata.date::string as ivw_date,
  d_obj.* 
FROM data as t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.json:data) d_obj;
```

I commented out more stuff to show the intent of where we are going:

[image]

So now we can flatten `d_obj` once we check it's a "LEVEL*" which is also what will become `system`:

```
SELECT
  t.json:metadata.site::STRING AS site,
  t.json:metadata.aggregation::string as aggregation,
  t.json:metadata.date::string as ivw_date,
  t.json:metadata.exported_at::string as exported_at,
  d_obj.key as system,
  t.json:metadata.version::string as version,
  level_obj.value:datetime::string as datetime,
  level_obj.value:pis::number as pis,
  level_obj.value:code::string as code,
  'fakedata' as FILE_NAME,
  UUID_STRING() as LOAD_ID,
  TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) as LOAD_DATE
FROM data as t,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => t.json:data) d_obj,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => d_obj.value) as level_obj
where d_obj.key like 'level%'
```

[image]

So now you should see how to unpack the data, and thus be able to map back to your data coming from your files.